# Apply a function on a data frame and return multiple data frames

Tags: r, xml, purrr

I have a data table with a column that contains xml formatted strings such as:

```
   str = '<root>
          <MatchData id="1234" >
             <PA>
                <Name val="John, Joseph, Smith" />
                <Address value="123 Smith St City" />
                <Gender value="M" />
             </PA>
          </MatchData>
          <MatchData id="1235">
             <PA>
                <Name val="Sarah, Amy, Jones" />
                <Address value="123 Jones St City" />
                <Gender value="F" />
             </PA>
          </MatchData>
       </root>'
```

For each row within the data table, I need to extract out the values to a new data table, and bind them together. Currently I can do this with a for loop as below, where I extract exact node into a row of a data table, and then append to the complete set:

```
library(data.table)
library(xml2)
library(purrr)

Data <- data.table(String = str)
All <- data.table(ID = '', Name = '', Address = '', Gender = '')

for (i in 1:nrow(Data)){

  tryCatch( { temp <- xml_find_all(read_xml(Data$String[i]), ".//MatchData") %>% 
    map_df(function(x) {
      list(
        ID=xml_attr(x, "id"),
        Name=xml_find_first(x, ".//Name")  %>% xml_attr("val"),
        Address=xml_find_first(x, ".//Address")  %>% xml_attr("value"),
        Gender=xml_find_first(x, ".//Gender")  %>% xml_attr("value")
      )
    }) %>% as.data.table() 
  }, silent = TRUE
  , error = function(e) {})


  All <- rbind(All,temp)

}
```

Can this be done within a function to speed up the process? I have tried however the output data table isn't quite right:

```
parseXMLStructure <- function(y){

   return <- xml_find_all(read_xml(y), ".//MatchData") %>% 
    map_df(function(x) {
      list(
         ID=xml_attr(x, "id"),
        Name=xml_find_first(x, ".//Name")  %>% xml_attr("val"),
        Address=xml_find_first(x, ".//Address")  %>% xml_attr("value"),
        Gender=xml_find_first(x, ".//Gender")  %>% xml_attr("value")
      )
    }) %>% as.data.table() 

}
x <- mapply(parseXMLStructure,Data$String)
```

Comment: One common approach is to `lapply` the thing you're doing to each row of the dataframe, so that the result is a list that I'll call `res`. (For clarity, `length(res)`=`nrow(df)`)  Once you have the `res` list, call `do.call(rbind,res)` to get everything appended together.  This is a generally better/faster approach than "growing" `All` by continually overwriting it.

Comment: For Future reader: Change `xml_find_all(read_xml(y), ".//MatchData")` to `xml_find_all(read_xml(Data$String[y]), ".//MatchData")` inside the function, then do `data.table::rbindlist(lapply(1:nrow(Data), function(x)parseXMLStructure(x)))`